# Get the URL of an iframe then alert it

Tags: javascript, iframe

So basically I'm trying to make a button so when you press it, it alerts the url the iframe is on.

My HTML:

```
<iframe id="iframeid"  scrolling="auto" width="100" height="100" src="http://www.google.com" >
</iframe>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Then for my Javascript I have:

```
function myFunction() {
alert(document.getElementById('iframeid').contentWindow.location.href);
}
```

Though when I press it it's not working. When I replace the alert with something else like "Potato" then it will work. Though for some reason it can't get the url, or maybe the frame. Any help accepted!

Answer (score 1):

When the frame is displaying a document on another origin (as in your example), there is no way to get the URL that is being displayed.

The URL might include personal data belonging to the user so your site is prevented from accessing it.

Always look at your JS console:

[image: screenshot]